# How to find at least 4 events happened in any 14 days window in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that contains events and dates. I want to find the patients who had the event at least 4 times in any 14 days period and return the row with the ID and the earliest event date of 4 or more events that occurred in R.

the data frame:

---

```
df <-data.frame(ID=c("P01","P01","P01","P01","P01","P01","P01","P02","P02","P02","P02","P02","P03","P03","P03","P03","P03","P03"),
        date=c("2019-07-08","2019-07-26","2019-07-27","2019-07-30","2019-08-01","2019-08-03","2019-08-05", "2019-09-08","2019-09-14","2020-06-20","2020-06-23","2020-06-30","2019-11-25","2019-11-26","2019-12-11","2019-12-12","2019-12-20","2019-12-23"))
```

---

output:

```
P01 2019-07-26
P03 2019-12-11
```

Comment: The data frame call does not work if copy and pasted, everything should be in quotes.

Comment: Do you want the earliest event for that ID, or the earliest event that starts off a "4 in 14" streak?

Answer (score 2):

Here I convert the dates to Date format, add a counting column, and then group by ID and count how many appearances occur in a 14 day window looking forward (current day + 13 days), and finally filter to only keep the first day for each ID where the window count is 4 or more.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date), count = 1) %>%
  arrange(ID, date) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(count14d = slider::slide_index_dbl(count, date, sum,
                                            .after = lubridate::days(13))) %>%
  filter(date == min(date[count14d >= 4])) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Result is the first rows that begin qualifying "4 in 14" streaks:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  ID    date       count count14d
  <chr> <date>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 P01   2019-07-26     1        6
2 P03   2019-12-11     1        4
```

Or, if you want the first event of any kind for these ID's you could add:

```
...%>%  
  select(ID) %>%
  left_join(df %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>% 
              group_by(ID) %>% summarize(first_event = min(date)))
```

to get:

```
Joining, by = "ID"
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  ID    first_event
  <chr> <date>     
1 P01   2019-07-08 
2 P03   2019-11-25
```

Comment: Thank you Jon. The first output is what I need, the first date that >=4 events occur within 14 days. I edited the question to clarify this